# Create an IdentityUser object from a method out of Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working on an `Asp.Net Core` project targeted `.Net 5` with `Microsoft Identity` and `Entity framework core` *(Code first approache)*.

In my project some entities will inherit from `IAuditProperties` interface.

**IAuditProperties:**
This interface used to read/write some audition info from/in any `Entity` that implement it.

```
string   CreatedBy    { get; set; }
DateTime CreatedOn    { get; set; }
bool     IsEdited     { get; set; }
string   LastEditor   { get; set; }
DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; }
```

In my project I wrote some extension methods that will write some auditon infos, all those extensions for any `Entity` that implemented the `IAuditProperties` interface.

**WriteCreationAudit extension method as example**

```
/// <summary>
/// Write audit properties for an <see cref="IAuditProperties"/> for the first creation
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj"><see cref="IAuditProperties"/> object to write in</param>
/// <param name="appUser">Current user</param>
public static void WriteCreationAudit( this IAuditProperties obj,AppUser appUser)
{
    obj.CreatedBy = appUser.FullName;
    obj.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.InMorocco();
    obj.IsEdited  = false;
}
```

**What is exactly the core issue?**

As you notice that the extention method `WriteCreationAudit` is recieves a `appUser` parameter, this parameter's type (`AppUser`) inherit from `IdentityUser`.

**So, the exact issue is How can I create object from `AppUser` without pass it as parameter from the `Controller` ?**

**How I handle this issue at this time?**
At this time I'm depending on `Controller`s and `DI` to get `AppUser` object and pass it to `WriteCreationAudit` method, and I don't love this technique.

So please, How can I achieve my goal about creating new object from `AppUser` from the extension method ? or if I can't achieve it is there any other good way ?
Massive thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depend on the circumstance, I would suggest 2 approaching ways, then take whichever that suit your case most... or even better, take the idea and implement it your way.

- Simple data was required

As your purposed, I saw every thing was required just a `FullName` and might be in the future `userId`. So, why just not simply put them somewhere in Jwt or even cookie depend on your authentication mechanism ? They're not such as ultra-secure information to guard. We can easily saw them [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml), even Jwt was designed to hold that kind of information. So, just inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into `DbContext` or repository if we make use of Repository pattern, take out User Info, then tweak a bit on the `SaveChanges` things.

- Data required to process was some kiind complex or need to be secured.

Make something like `BaseInfoRequest` object that contain all the infomations we need, set them on some upper middleware and store in cache, with absolute expiration that equivalent to request timeout, the key should be `HttpContext.Session.Id` + "some constants string" that represent request infoObject. Then take them out from the cache wherever we need.

Just a small note: If we doesn't expose the `UserName` for example, but `userId` only, which mean foreach request we need to take `UserName` from somewhere. That's not a good idea in production scenarios. Take some consider about them to balance things out.

Comment: For the longest time I always do that small note thing, use userId to get the data from server instead of just trust the data from request (except userId of course). It's a performance hit for security. Also to deal with single source of truth... I wish there's some way or guidelines on how to access the trade-offs

Comment: If the project was that level of security, then we could reduce calling to server by cache it for each `userId`, and whenever `userName` was allowed to change, clear that cache. Base on the project stucture we could choose between various cache implementation. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is some doc about `MemoryCache`

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with DI inject to controller then pass the param to the extension method?

I just recalled a while back Microsoft said don't inject SignInManager and UserManager in razor component (also not razor page/the razor component with @page). Instead, extend UserClaimsPrincipalFactory to add claims like:

```
public class AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory
    : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser, IdentityRole>
{
    public AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    { }

    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(AppUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim("FullName", user.FullName?? ""));


        identity.AddClaims(claims);
        return principal;
    }
}
```

I agree with @Gordon Khanh Ng. and this is just implementation difference

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common behaviour and there are many ways to achieve this. Here is how you can do this. This is probably the easiest way

Override your SaveChanges()/ SaveChangesAsync() method in DbContext class. Also inject the IHttpContextAccessor in the constructor.

Then use this code inside your DbContext class.

> The GetCurrentUserId() method may differ depending on your Identity implementation.

```
        private string GetCurrentUserId()
        {
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext ?? null;
            if (httpContext.HasValue() && httpContext.User.HasValue())
            {
                var authenticatedUsername = httpContext.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "sub")
                    .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

                return authenticatedUsername;
            }

            return null;
        }
        
        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Detached && e.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
            
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                if (entry.Entity is IAuditProperties trackable)
                {
                    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    var user = GetCurrentUserId();
                    switch (entry.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            trackable.CreatedAt = now;
                            trackable.CreatedBy = user;
                            trackable.IsEdited = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```